# Php code working fine on wamp server but not on the an other one. Unexpected character in input

Tags: php, vmware, wampserver

Basicly I have is situation:

1. Wamp server on the host (physical machine) win7 x64
2. Php code editor on host too
3. Wamp server on virtual machine win7 x32 (VMware Player). It runs the code of the host machine (shared by Folder Sharing of VMware).

Wow when I change anything in the PHP code I get this message:

```
 Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in "file name" on line "line number"
```

I created this machine to test my code by slow net connection (can adjust it on the VMware). and the old code i already have works fine. Just when I change something it gives me that error.

I notice here that the code (with changes) works fine on the host WampServer.

I want to add the way i do to my code (on the host) accessible for WampServer on the VM: I deleted the original www-folder on the VM and created a shortcut using this command:

```
mklink /D "C:\wamp\www" "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\mysite"
```

Where "mysite" is the sharing name of the host-www-folder on the VM machine. I tried the command mklink /J and /H but they don't link non-local volumes.
An other notice is that when I restart the VM the already Changed code work fine

Comment: It would seem to be that it is not keeping the files in sync... Have had similar issues with Rsync on Windows. When you restart the VM it sees the changes and is fine.

Comment: @Jarvis thank you, though i don't think VMware is creating an image copy of the shared folder (imagine to share Gigs sized folders!!) I think it's more accessing and reading the shared folders from the host directory and transferring them to the VM as virtual network folder when ever they are needed. And I think you are about sync problem (it seems the VMware is not providing the files as it should be to WampServer). When i open the changed file with Notepad++ on the VM (it open alright), a space (to activated saving) and save the file it works fine then

Comment: Oh it is definitely not copying the full shared folder, or if it is, it does so smartly... It definitely doesn't seem to be marking the file as changed properly... That is interesting that if you open it on the VM and then save it again it works fine...

Comment: @Jarvis Yes for me it looks like a bug. WampServer on the host (that i run to the same time) loads the page perfectly.

Comment: For those facing same issue this is not an answer but a work around. i turned to oracle virtual box, which has not network speed limitation (outbound only after my seaches) so i installed  a speed limiter on the guest (in my case netbalancer)